# Is $U = \lbrace (1),(2),(1,2),(2,1) \rbrace$ a permutation? or a permutation of a power set?

Tags: permutations, terminology

## Question

If for a set $S= \lbrace 1 , 2 \rbrace$ the set $T = \lbrace (1,2),(2,1) \rbrace$ is refered to as a *permutation*,
 then how would an alternative set $U = \lbrace (1),(2),(1,2),(2,1) \rbrace$ be refered to with respect to $S$?

## Background

The background is that it is easy for any set $S_n = \lbrace 1,2, \dots n \rbrace$ with $|S_n|=n$,  to calculate number of elements in $T_n$ as being $n!$.

Getting the number of elements in a set $U_n =  \lbrace (1),(2),(1,2),(2,1),\dots (n,n-1,\cdots,1,2),(n,n-1,\cdots,2,1) \rbrace$
that is being constructed in a similar fashion as the $U$ above for the case of $|S|=2$, but for $S$ having $n$ elements gives me trouble.

## helpful would be

to know a **more correct term** to describe/refer the kind of set $U_n$.

I think it is incorrect to say that $U_n$ is merely another type of permutation, as for instance the elements of $U_n$ are tuples of varying degree.

**Does permutation require that the image set would consist solely of a single type of n-tuple**?

To make explicit examples of $U_3$ and $U_4$ (as wisely suggested in the comment )
$$U_3 = \lbrace (1),(2),(3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1)\rbrace$$

$|U_3|=15$

$$U_4 = \lbrace (1),(2),(3),(4),
(1,2),
(1,3),
(1,4),
(2,1),
(2,3),
(2,4),
(3,1),
(3,2),
(3,4),
(4,1),
(4,2),
(4,3),
(1,2,3),
(1,2,4),
(1,3,2),
(1,3,4),
(1,4,2),
(1,4,3),
(2,1,3),
(2,1,4),
(2,3,1),
(2,3,4),
(2,4,1),
(2,4,3),
(3,1,2),
(3,1,4),
(3,2,1),
(3,2,4),
(3,4,1),
(3,4,2),
(4,1,2),
(4,2,1),
(4,1,3),
(4,3,1),
(4,2,3),
(4,3,2),
(1,2,3,4),
(1,2,4,3),
(1,3,2,4),
(1,3,4,2),
(1,4,2,3),
(1,4,3,2),
(2,1,3,4),
(2,1,4,3),
(2,3,1,4),
(2,3,4,1),
(2,4,1,3),
(2,4,3,1),
(3,1,2,4),
(3,1,4,2),
(3,2,1,4),
(3,2,4,1),
(3,4,1,2),
(3,4,2,1),
(4,1,2,3),
(4,1,3,2),
(4,2,1,3),
(4,2,3,1),
(4,3,1,2),
(4,3,2,1)
\rbrace$$

$|U_4|= 4 + 4*3 + 4*6 + 4*6 = 64 $

## Update

A similar question has also been asked on stackexchange in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079038/what-is-the-number-of-all-set-permutations-in-a-power-set
Similar with respect to the question to calculate the number of permutations of a power set

Comment: The pattern defining $U_n$ is unclear. Can you state $U_3$ and $U_4$ in full?

Comment: If I take your meaning correctly, then $\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$ is referred to as a permutation of $S=\{1,2\}$ because it can be viewed as a function $\pi:S\to S$ (single-valued binary relation) such that $1\mapsto 2$ and $2\mapsto 1$ (in relation notation, $1\pi 2$ and $2\pi 1$) which also happens to be bijective. The same cannot be said for $U$, so no, I don't think you can denote any permutation on $S$ by it (unless I mistake your meaning).

Comment: @JonathanY. This bijective notion is what I also read on [wikipedia's permuation article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) and that might help me know what it is not (and even answer the question). Yet the $|U_n|$ seems to be "structured" and by having a term I might read how to calculate it for a give n $n$

Comment: I don't follow. Are you trying to prove that there are exactly $n!$ permutation on $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ by constructing these $U_n$, or have I completely missed your point?

Comment: @JonathanY. It's much more a real world issue. I compose passphrases of parts which consitute the elements of $S = \lbrace "this", "is","secret"\rbrace$ and eventually test the passphrases like $ U_3= \lbrace "this", "is", "secret", "thisis","thisecret","isthis","issecret" \dots "secretisthis" \rbrace $ and I wanted to calculate how many trials there will be for all possible combinations. Looking into combinatorics I read permutations, which I assume is at best a related term for the problem. I wished I was better in explaining the issue, but maybe the example gives the idea

Comment: Why isn't $(4,1,2)$ an element of $U_4$?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger it should be. It got lost, mostly I guess because the formula was so huge already and I lost sight, thanks I will correct

Comment: @humanityANDpeace I think $|U_4|$ should be $4+4\cdot3+4\cdot3\cdot2+4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=64$.

Comment: My guess is $|U_n|=\lfloor n!e\rfloor-1$. If you include the empty tuple, you get $|U_n|=\lfloor n!e\rfloor$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger is $e$ in your formula  the Eulers's number? How can I read the formula for $|U_n|$. ?

Comment: Yes. And $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor of $x$ (the largest integer less than $x$). For example, $\lfloor3.14\rfloor=3$. It basically gets rid of the bit after the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, a permutation is a way to arrange a set of things. So, if you have the set: $$S = \{1, 2\}$$, there are $2!$ ways (which is 2) to permute this set. As a result, $$U = \{(1), (2), (1, 2), (2, 1)\}$$ is not a permutation, except for the subset $$S_U = \{(1, 2), (2, 1)\} \subseteq U$$ But, there is no specified term for set $U$ which isn't a permutation, so the most sensible term for that [to me] would be a **non-permutation**.

Comment: thanks. It is an idea to call it **non-permutation**, which implies that is is not a permutation. Only I expect that many concepts in mathematics are not a permutation neither.

Comment: And remember, there are $n!$ ways to permute a set $S = \{1, 2, \cdot \cdot \cdot, n\}$ using the **same amount of elements in the set**.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an approximative partial answer, which I hope can be expanded still later, while already giving some hint.

Both terms [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) and [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) already have a meaning different to the concept as examplified in $U$. A *permutation* for instance seems to be a set in which the tuples are of a an equal *tuple length*.

The somewhat more correct term for $U$ would be [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) that has been stripped of the [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set) and whose elemets have been substituted by their their respective *permutations*.

a *power set* of $S_3 = \lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace$ would be
$P = \lbrace \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace , \lbrace 1 \rbrace, \lbrace 2 \rbrace, \lbrace 3 \rbrace, \lbrace 1,2 \rbrace, \lbrace 2,3 \rbrace , \lbrace 1 , 3 \rbrace , \lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace\rbrace $

the formula for the cardinality of $|P(U_n)|= 2^n$ when has itself $|U_n|=n$

With reference at https://oeis.org/A000522 which looks at the sequence $1, 2, 5, 16, 65, 326, 1957, 13700, 109601, 986410, 9864101, 108505112, 1302061345, 16926797486, 236975164805, 3554627472076, \dots$

it might be that what we have with the examplified $U$ is an

> arrangements of a set with n elements: a(n) =
> Sum_{k=0..n} n!/k!.

which is presented as

> number of paths (without loops) in the complete graph on n+2 vertices
> starting at one vertex v1 and ending at another v2. Example: when n=2
> there are 5 paths in the complete graph with 4 vertices starting at
> the vertex 1 and ending at the vertex 2:
> (12),(132),(142),(1342),(1432) so a(2) = 5. - Avi Peretz
> (njk(AT)netvision.net.il), Feb 23 2001; comment corrected by Jonathan
> Coxhead, Mar 21 2003

## Formula

The formula as provided in the comment from @AkivaWeinberger for the number of paths is then

$$|U_n|=\lfloor n!e\rfloor -1$$

Comment: You're right, this is a power set of set $U$. The set of all the subsets of a set is known as a power set, so that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A *permutation* of a set $S$ is simply a bijective function $\pi:S\to S$. (This terminology also makes sense for infinite sets, although its use is typically restricted to countable sets.)

A *function* $f:A\to B$ is a subset of $A \times B$ that satisfies the condition:

> For all $a \in A$ there exists exactly one $b \in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$

and we write this as $f(a) = b$.

Now, your set $T$ is a subset of $S \times S$ that satisfies the above condition, so it is a function, with $S(1)=2$ and $S(2) = 1$. And it is also a bijection; it is its own inverse. Hence $T$ is a permutation of $S$.

Your set $U$ is not even a function, so it is far from being a permutation.

Comment: This way $U$ might seem far from a permutation, yet one might argue that a generation of $U$ would be following the rule to create a set which first is the somewhat power set of $S$ and that second has all its the power set members permutations included. It hence seems to me not exactly far fetched to be guided to the term *permutation*. Is it not maybe that $U$ is something? and if so this something would be a joing of a powerset and its permutations ?

Comment: I can't make sense of this at all.

Comment: So you say that @humanityANDpeace's set $U$ isn't a function. Can you prove that in any way?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue: Of course it's not a function, at least not according to the standard definition that I give in my answer. It's not even a subset of $S \times S$. If you have your own idea of what a function is, you had better let us know.

Comment: No, my "idea" of a what a function is is the same as you guys' (probably): A function is a function **iff** if an element in one set is related to exactly one element in another set. What I was asking for was a proof that the set $U$ was a function (which you may have already gave).